# PHP selected Option

Tags: php, chained

I am working on a Chained menu, but now I want to get the second menu filled in by what actually is selected in first.

This means I want something like jQuery has, "selected.index" but in PHP. **I don't want to use ajax**

All infos should come from the database.

The older Post just have fixed values, but I want to be able to change values in my Database without problems.

```html
<?php /* $_GET Variablen in lokale Variablen übernehmen */ $a=$ _GET[ 'a']; $b=$ _GET[ 'b']; /* Eine kleine Berechnung */ $erg=$ a * $b; /* * Folgend die Ausgabe die per Ajax zurück an die Hauptseite gesendet wird * * Es ist auch möglich die Inhalte erst
in eine Variable zu speichern, * die dann am Ende des Skripts ausgegeben wird. * * Bsp: * $content="Hallo Welt" ; * $content .="Das ist eine Ausgabe" ; * echo $content; */ ?>Dies ist eine Ausgabe der Seite "auswertung.php"
<br />
<br />Ihre Eingaben:
<br />a =
<?php echo $a ?>
<br />b =
<?php echo $b ?>
<br />
<select name="auswahl1" name="ceg">
  <option value="container" <?php if($status=='container' ) { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>>
    <?php echo $a ?>
  </option>
  <option value="container" <?php if($status=='container' ) { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>>
    <?php echo $b ?>
  </option>
  <option value="container" <?php if($status=='container' ) { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>>
    <?php echo $erg ?>
  </option>
</select>
<?php if(isset($_POST[ 'auswahl1'])) // Checks if 1Ste Drop Down menu has a value. $value1=$_POST[ 'auswahl1']; ?>
<select name="auswahl1" onChange="this.form.submit();">
  <option value="container" <?php if($ceg==1) { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>>
    <?php echo $b ?>
  </option>
  <option value="container" <?php if($ceg==2) { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>>
    <?php echo $a ?>
  </option>
</select>
<br />Ergebnis:
<?php echo $erg ?>
```

Comment: PHP is not going to run in that code snippet. It's for HTML/CSS/JS only.

Comment: I know but code Sempel  couldnt get all lines somehow

Comment: What's *code Sempel*?

Comment: its the button to input just the quellcode

Comment: Are you using some translation tool? English would be helpful.